# How to disable FuckAdBlock

Tags: javascript, adblock

so most of you must be using the **AdBlock** or **AdBlock Plus** plugin in your browsers to stop the annoying ads and popups from getting displayed.

But now some devs have developed a script [FuckAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock) that helps the site owner to detect whether I have **AdBlock** or **AdBlock Plus** on my browser or not.

My question is how can I disable this script.

I had few ideas that I tried but didn't get anywhere.

1. From the chome dev tools -> Source, I copied the link address of the script and added to blocked address in *AdBlock Plus*. Still the file is being loaded. Don't know why.
2. This script is adding

```
    if(window.fuckAdBlock === undefined) {
        window.fuckAdBlock = new FuckAdBlock({
            checkOnLoad: true,
            resetOnEnd: true
        });
    }
```

So I wanted to add an `Object.observe` on `window.fuckAdBlock`, so that whenever it got changed I can change it back to `null`. But unfortunately I don't know how to use it properly.

3. At last I disabled the JS on that particular site. It disabled the plugin but also some other functionality also.

Comment: Hmmm... Can't tell if this is a good fit or not. It's a programming issue, but for a completely different purpose.

Comment: Ah, a good old arms race... reminds me [of this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: Also, *"so most of you must be using the AdBlock or AdBlock Plus"*? You're jumping to conclusions, especially after the [AdBlock Plus controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus#Controversy_over_ad_filtering_and_ad_whitelisting).

Comment: @zeta, :D yes you right. could you plz post the link to help me and others.

Comment: @christopher: It's off-topic in its current state. It's asking for a tool, a library, or code in order to get rid of a problem. It's much better suited for Super User.

Comment: @Zeta the solution provided was for a tool, library or code. This was trying to work out a software solution to the aforementioned problem. That's what threw me. But fair enough!

Comment: pretty sure you can easily diasble it with one line of code using the "My filters" function of the uBlock Origin Chrome Extension. dont remember what it was, just remember seeing is on reddit. I was looking for it and found this instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Somebody already solved the problem [here](https://github.com/Mechazawa/FuckFuckAdblock). The script is quite short (103 lines). It works by changing some values in the FuckAdBlock script.

I wonder when the FuckFuckFuckAdblock script will be written though.

Comment: Well, I found this issue because a user decided to install FuckFuckAdBlock in Microsoft Edge, and it generates thousands of errors on any web page that *doesn't* have `FuckAdBlock` installed (and consequently spams our error reporting service...).

I couldn't submit a PR to add proper error handling to FuckFuckAdBlock, so I created FuckFuckFuckAdBlock instead: https://github.com/mruhlin/FuckFuckFuckAdblock

Please use this one if you're an Edge user.